# Setting Up Flask DB2 connection

Tags: python, flask, db2

I am trying to connect my flask application to a DB2 database,but somehow I am unable to do. here is what I am trying to do,
I am using flask extension `flask_db2` for this purpose and below is how I am trying to connect

`from flask import Flask
from flask_db2 import DB2
app = Flask(__name__)`

`@app.route('/')
def index()
     cur = db.connection.cursor("DATABASE=name;HOSTNAME=host;PORT=60000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password)`

Comment: Are you missing a line `db = DB2(app)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_db2 import DB2

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['DB2_DATABASE'] = 'sample'
app.config['DB2_HOSTNAME'] = 'localhost'
app.config['DB2_PORT'] = 50000
app.config['DB2_PROTOCOL'] = 'TCPIP'
app.config['DB2_USER'] = 'db2inst1'
app.config['DB2_PASSWORD'] = 'db2inst1'

db = DB2(app) #You forgot that


@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur = db.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(...)
```

**First**: You forgot to have an object to use the flask db2 module.

*The DB2(app) is a constructor for your Flask extension and will bind your application to this module.*

where as

```
db = DB2(app)
```

Initialises your db object with help of your extension's constructor which you can further use for your Database operations.

**Secondly**: use app configs to play with DB2 credentials. (This step should be done before you bind the app)

**Third**: You can execute your query like this

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM users") #something like that
```

I hope I have clarified :D just drop message. Ill try helping more.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer .

Comment: Done Captain :D

Comment: Thank you Noor, where do i pass the database information and user credentials , is it with in `cur = db.connection.cursor()` ?

Comment: Thank you Noor,  this really helps

Comment: Hi Noor, would it be possible for you to help me with another question that i had posted, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199981/upload-and-display-csv-file-on-flask?noredirect=1#comment87417031_50199981

Comment: I would have :D, its closed.